# Is there a way to get the html report from Istanbul while it is running?

Tags: node.js, testing, code-coverage, istanbul

I have a test suite that takes some time to run (i.e., half an hour).
I would like to check progress in the html report while the tests are running (i.e., by refreshing the page in the browser).

Comment: So you want to peek into the coverage before tests are finished? As far as I know, Istanbul only creates code coverage reports... how can those be created before tests are through? If you want to check the current status of tests, why can't you read the console? I assume whatever testing framework you're using writes data to the console, no? I suppose you could always run separate `nyc` commands that target specific directories? idk.. seems like an odd thing to want.

Comment: It's difficult to give an exact answer without knowing the environment the tests are running in, but in a browser Istanbul stores results incrementally to a fairly complex object `window.__coverage__`.  I use this to console.log a summary of lines not covered during the run, so it's also possible to trigger a full report say in `afterEach()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
npx jest --config ./jest.config.cjs --coverage --watchAll
```

This way, Istanbul is regenerated every time I make a change in a test. Is listening to my changes.

Very useful to track what I am still left to cover in the test I am implementing.